# Free, simple & open source dashbaord

Tags: dashboard

We are trying to build a new dashboard. The design of dashboard is pretty simple. We are reluctant to go towards aspx since we do not have a IIS server right now, and it would not be possible to install one. 
But we have a SharePoint site specific for our application.

Is there any external tool using which I can establish connection to back end, and create the dashboard and publish it in SharePoint. I have developed few reports using SSRS and published in SharePoint, but SSRS dashboards doesn’t look visually pleasing. Is there any other tools available to create dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap is a responsive front end development framework from Twitter.

They give template for Dashboard.

See if that can help. http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/admin-dashboard/

Comment: Hello, Is there a way to connect to DB from this. We do not see an option to connect to DB.

Comment: No it's just html/css. You should make your project following MVC architecture. Learn more about it.